# Proving that $f(x)=rx+x_0 $ is open in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\varepsilon_n)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following example in my lectures notes:

In $(\mathbb{R}^n,\varepsilon_n)$ let $ B=B(O,1)$ be the open ball with center the origin $O$ and radious $1$.

$B$ is homeomorphic to any open ball $ B(x_0,r)$ with rispect to the euclidean metric. In fact, it is enough to osserve that the mapping  $f(x)=rx+x_0 $ has as an inverse $f^{-1}(y)=r^{-1}(y-x_0)$,and that $f$ and $ f^{-1}$ are both continuous and that $f(B)=B(x_0,r)$ (that is that f is open, it maps open sets into open sets)

I am having trouble proving $f(B)=B(x_0,r)$. Intuitively I know it must be like that, but I am having trouble writing it down formally. Besides I am not so comfortable with the notation since they look like numbers but since we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we are dealing with vector and matrices here.

So far I have only that the origin is mapped to the new center $x_0$: $f(O)=f((0,0...,0))=r0+x_0=x_0$

How do I go about it?

Comment: Your title is somewhat confusing since *the function* $f$ isn't open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it isn't even a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Michael Burr  I mean open function, a function is open when it maps open sets to open sets

Comment: The condition of being open is a very different condition from being an open function.

Comment: @Michael Burr do you mean I should title it open function instead of just open? but saying that f is open couldn't possibly mean f is a set, since it is a function, could it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement $f(B)=B(x_0,r)$ is a statement about set equality, so use that style of proof:

Suppose that $y\in B$, then $\|y\|<1$.  Then $f(y)=ry+x_0$, which means that we scale $y$ by $r$ and add $x_0$.  Then, $\|x_0-f(y)\|=\|ry\|=r\|y\|<r$.  Therefore, $f(y)\in B(x_0,r)$.

On the other hand, suppose that $z\in B(x_0,r)$.  Then $\|z-x_0\|<r$.  Let $y=\frac{1}{r}(z-x_0)$.  Then, $f(y)=r\left(\frac{1}{r}(z-x_0)\right)+x_0=z.$  Moreover, $\|y\|=\frac{1}{r}\|z-x_0\|<1$.  Therefore, $z\in f(B)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, If I may ask, how could I prove continuity of f?, I am just assuming it since it looks like a linear function but in several variables, Could I take an open set and check that the preimage is an open set?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Checking that preimages are open is the standard way of checking continuity in this context. That would be my suggestion.

Comment: It is not a linear function, but an affine function.  But, this is continuous (as can be shown with a similar argument as above).

Answer (score 0):

Let $y \in B(x_0,r)$. Then by definition $\|y-x_0\| < r$. Then $\|r^{-1}(y-x_0)\| = |r^{-1}|\|y-x_0\| <r^{-1}r = 1$. So the point $r^{-1}(y-x_0)$ is in $B(0,1)$. It is easy to verify that $f(r^{-1}(y-x_0)) = y$. So $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to prove that $f(B)=B(x_0, r)$, you need to show that $f(B)\subset B(x_0, r)$ and $B(x_0, r) \subset f(B)$. And to prove that $A \subset C$, you need to pick an element of $A$ and show that it is an element of $C$ as well.